# javax.mail.Session in cloudBees

Tags: java, cloudbees, sendgrid, jakarta-mail

I am developing a webapp in cloudbees platform and trying to add functionality for sending mail.

I am following https://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/SendGrid  documentation and as per the document we can get the mail session using below:

```
 Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
 Session session = (Session) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env/mail/SendGrid");
```

But when running thie code in cloud i am getting:

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.mail.Session cannot be cast to javax.mail.Session.
```

the problem seems to be with javax.mail.jar

i have downloaded the latest jar from https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home .

**As i understand the version which is required in cloud bees is different from what i am deploying.Can anyone  help in getting correct jar for this particular purpose.**

Note: I have added send grid to my stack in cloudBees.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have more than one version of the javax.mail. 
Indeed, the java mail session jars should be already provided by the container.

You can refer to this, as example: https://github.com/CloudBees-community/tomcat7-sendgrid-clickstart/blob/master/pom.xml

Try to remove your mail jar and if it still does not work and you are using maven try using the dependency plugin with

mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose

to check if you have conflicts with mails dependencies.

Comment: i am not using maven so have to place the jars manually.also i have created a dynamic web project and not from template cloudbees provide..i have only one jar which i downloaded .

Comment: if you are using tomcat (if not, which stack are you using?), the jar should be already provided in the container. If you add another one, you would probably get an error. What does it happen if you remove it? I know you are not using the cloudbees project, I was just suggesting to refer to it as example, since you are using a cloudbees stack.

Answer (score 0):

**Duplicate Problem Resolved with Spring Framework on Cloudbees**

I had the same problem only from Spring and can confirm it was from including javax-mail in the Maven dependencies (which also brings in the mail jar).  After taking out the dependency/jar file I was having a problem with the constructor for org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl not liking the type of the argument from jndi, however. At least the original error seemed to be objecting to the same class rather than saying it didn't know the type/name/etc. Finally, taking out passing the session to the constructor and putting it in the property (which in theory should do the same thing, I believe) fixed the problem:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="mailSource" 
  jndi-name="java:comp/env/mail/SendGrid"
  expected-type="javax.mail.Session" /> 

<bean id="mailSender"
  class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
  <property name="session" ref="mailSource" />
</bean>
```